# phpmyadmin в lamp-server

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, php, mysql, ubuntu

Поставил lamp - server в убунту 11,04. Все работает. Установил phpmyadmin (`sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`). После установки написал `localhost/phpmyadmin` и он мне ответил, что документ не найден. Так куда же он установился и почему не работает?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ubuntu и phpMyAdmin](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/387926/ubuntu-%d0%b8-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу запустить phpmyadmin (elementary os)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433746/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-phpmyadmin-elementary-os)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www
```