# Ubuntu и phpMyAdmin

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Установил `lamp` и отдельно установил `phpmyadmin`, который не вызывается. Сама директория `PMA` есть и сам сервер работает, но Admin нет. Помогите его запустить.

**Обновление**

В `var/www` и туда же установлен `phpmyadmin`, ну, в общем, я этот вопрос решил, но появился другой: как открыть ftp доступ к `localhost`?

**Обновление 2**

Я открыл права на `папкуvar/www`, и `pma` впихнул в папку `var/www`, и  переименовал в `phpmyadmin`. И так это всё заработало, и уже установил 4cms, и не так сложно - чуток манипуляций, отличается от установки на windows-server, но cms WordPress запросила обновление. И, как ни странно, для этого надо доступ к FTP, но это же на локалке - вот тут я в ступоре.

Comment: @maximcka, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: В какую директорию ты устанавливал phpmyadmin? Что написано в httpd.conf? 

Comment: Опишите здесь ваше решение и задайте новый вопрос про открытие дотупа по FTP.

Answer (score 1):

[@maximсka](/users/27309/maxim%D1%81ka), такое бывает, когда вордпресс запускается от иного пользователя, нежели того, который владеет файлами. Решается это идиотским wordpress-way: добавить в index.php строчку `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');`.

Comment: что то не работает -- wordpress-way - попробывал - ноль null

Comment: решением было открыть права на всю папку с установленным сайтом