# Не могу запустить phpmyadmin (Elementary OS)

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, elementary-os

После установки phpmyadmin, не могу запустить его. Пишет

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить на какой сервер устанавливали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

возможно, при установке пакета *phpmyadmin* вы не добавили автоматическую конфигурацию для установленного *http-сервера*.

можно повторить процедуру конфигурации такой командой:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

и в диалоге

> Please choose the web server that should be automatically configured to run phpMyAdmin.
>
> Web server to reconfigure automatically:

отметить пункт с нужным *http-сервером* (скорее всего, это будет *apache2*).

навигация между элементами диалога осуществляется клавишей <kbd>tab</kbd>, перемешение по списку — стрелками вверх/вниз, отметить пункт в списке можно клавишей <kbd>пробел</kbd>.

после завершения конфигурации (если был выбран *apache2*), в каталоге доступных модулей `/etc/apache2/conf-available/` должен появиться файл `phpmyadmin.conf`, а в каталоге включенных модулей `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/` — символическая ссылка на этот файл.

также *http-сервер* должен автоматически перезапуститься для принятия новых установок. можно и самостоятельно перезапустить:

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```