# Ошибка Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, symfony2

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   (тоже самое и с root).

*Симфони* выдает эту ошибку после попытки создать базу `php app/console doctrine:database:create`.

Переустанавливал как [здесь](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset) — не помогло. Переустанавливал *Lamp* — тоже не помогло. Давал *user'ам* все привилегии, в том числе и создавать базы.

Вот они сами:

```
---------------+
| localhost                     | root             | * |
| harmonica                     | root             | * |
| 127.0.0.1                     | root             | * |
| ::1                           | root             | * |
| localhost                     | debian-sys-maint | * |
| localhost                     | myuser           | * |
| locdalhost                    | root
```

Когда пытался поставить *phpmyadmin*, после ввода всех паролей, установщик выдавал ошибку:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Долго вожусь с этой ошибкой. Просмотрел темы и на обычном *stock'е*, рецепты не помогли.

Мог что-то упустить?

Comment: locdalhost - странное имя хоста...

Comment: Да убрал этого юзера, он добавился когда я давал права root через GRANT и ошибся c написанием хоста. Теперь все так же, только без последней строчки..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### про apache, php и mysql-server

во-первых, я бы рекомендовал не ставить какие-то сторонние сборки (*lamp* и т.п.) вместо отлично поддерживаемых и хорошо взаимно-интегрированных дистрибутивных пакетов `mysql-server`, `apache`, `php`.

для установки этих (и всех зависимых) пакетов (и для связки *php* с *apache* и *mysql*) можно выполнить такую, например, команду:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql
```

пароль пользователя *mysql*-базы данных *root* (если не был запрошен при установке пакетов) меняется абсолютно штатными [средствами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427773/178576).

после создания базы данных (командой типа `create database имя-базы-данных default charset utf8;` в «оболочке» `mysql`) можно создать (в той же «оболочке») и пользователя для доступа к этой базе. примерно так:

```
> grant all privileges on имя-базы-данных.* to пользователь@localhost identified by 'пароль';
```

### про «оболочку» mysql

эта программа входит в пакет *mysql-client* (устанавливается автоматически по зависимостям от, например, вышеприведённой команды `apt-get install ...`).

вызывается с указанием пользователя, запросом пароля и опциональным указанием базы данных, например, так:

```
$ mysql -u root -p [имя-базы-данных]
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
...
mysql>
```

после удачного запуска можно вводить *sql-команды* (типа `create database ...` и т.п.).

### про phpmyadmin

устанавливается пакет, как и обычно:

```
$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

при установке будет предложено добавить нужные настройки в конфигурацию *http-сервера*. подробнее смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433800/178576).