# Как сменить пароль от пользователя root при входе в phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, root

Я не знаю пароль от root phpmyadmin. Пробовал вот это:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
/usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
mysql
```

Выдавало ошибку: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'stepan'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
дальше пытался ввести пароль от своего юзера, через -p писало:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'stepan'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Вообщем не понимаю как его сменить, чтобы входило.

UPD: спустя 2 часа все заработало!

Comment: Даже через sudo mysql -v отклоняет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435643/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-access-denied-for-user-myuserlocalhost-using-password-yes
Ссылка на ответ

Comment: там нет инструкции как его сменить. просто выводит конфиги на экран

Comment: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
такая штука

Comment: ввести пустой пароль тоже не получается Вход без пароля запрещен при конфигурации (смотрите AllowNoPassword)

Comment: инструкция там приведена: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427773/178576

Comment: Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.24, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
пишет

Comment: При запуске общими средствами пишет это: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: Следовал этим инструкциям <https://900913.ru/2017/10/06/mysqld-sock-not-found/> Теперь просто поменялся номер ошибки с (2) на (13)

Comment: Спустя 2 часа копания в файлах конфигов и гугла у  меня все встало!